# Typeable instance for Constraint tupling

Tags: haskell, data-kinds, constraint-kinds

I'm trying to derive a `Typeable` instance for tupled constraints. See the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, AutoDeriveTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Typeable

data Foo (p :: (*, *))

data Dict ctx where
    Dict :: ctx => Dict ctx
  deriving (Typeable)

deriving instance Typeable '(,)
deriving instance Typeable Typeable
deriving instance Typeable Show

works :: IO ()
works = print (typeRep (Proxy :: Proxy (Foo '(Bool, Char))))

alsoWorks :: IO ()
alsoWorks = print (typeRep (Dict :: Dict (Show Bool)))

fails :: IO ()
fails = print (typeRep (Dict :: Dict (Show Bool, Typeable Bool)))

main :: IO ()
main = works >> alsoWorks >> fails
```

If you compile this with `-fprint-explicit-kinds`, the following error is given:

```
    No instance for (Typeable
                   (Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint) (,))
```

Is there a way to derive such an instance? Everything I try refuses to disambiguate from the `★ -> ★ -> ★` constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC can not currently make a `Typeable` instance, or any other instance, for `(,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint`. The type constructor `(,)` only has kind `* -> * -> *`. [There is no type constructor for products of the kind `Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7485). The constructor `(,)` is overloaded to construct both tuples and products of `Constraint`s, but has no corresponding type constructor when used to make a product of `Constraint`s.

If we did have a type constructor for products of `Constraint`s we should be able to define an instance as follows. For this, we'll pretend `(,)` is also a type constructor with kind `(,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint`. To define an instance for it, we'd use `KindSignatures` and import `GHC.Exts.Constraint` to be able to talk about the kind of constraints explicitly

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
import Data.Typeable

deriving instance Typeable ((,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint)
```

If we do this now, it results in the following error, due to the kind of the `(,)` type constructor.

```
The signature specified kind `Constraint
                              -> Constraint -> Constraint',
  but `(,)' has kind `* -> * -> *'
In the stand-alone deriving instance for
  `Typeable ((,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint)'
```

The [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package also works with products of constraints, and includes [the following note](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4/docs/Data-Constraint.html#v:-42--42--42-).

> due to the hack for the kind of `(,)` in the current version of GHC we can't actually make instances for `(,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint`

I presume the hack Edward Kmett is referring to is the overloading of the `(,)` constructor for `Constraint`s without a corresponding type constructor.

Comment: The error message `No instance for (Typeable (Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint) (,))` seems to imply that a type constructor exists *internally* somehow.  If it only had a name we could get at...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is not currently possible.  There's a revealing comment in the [latest version](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4/docs/Data-Constraint.html) of `constraint`:

> due to the hack for the kind of (,) in the current version of GHC we can't actually make instances for (,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint

Comment: Your comment about kmett it harmful to the community. Not disparaging his abilities in the least, but let's not have gods.

Comment: @luqui Very well, replaced by something hopefully innocuous.